# JAVA constructors (I'm about to smash my computer with a baseball bat)

Tags: java

Okay, I'm really frustrated here.  I am taking the second part of my Intro to Programming class this semester.  We did C++ last semester and now we're doing JAVA.  We have jumped into everything rather quickly in my opinion.  I believe this is because we're expected to apply our knowledge of C++ to JAVA since they are somewhat similar.  I guess this makes sense.  I'm just mad right now because I've been scouring Google, etc in an attempt to understand.

There are two files/classes - RectangleDemo and Rectangle.  RectangleDemo is the main.
We were asked to write code that could calculate area and perimeter.  My problem is this.
When I add a new constructor my original class and its object in 'RectangleDemo' now doesn't work.  Furthermore, my compiler cannot find the symbol for the new constructor.

heres the code...

```
public class RectangleDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle();

        double theArea;
        double thePerimeter;

        myRect.setLength(25);
        myRect.setWidth(5);

        theArea = myRect.area();

        thePerimeter = myRect.perim();

        System.out.println("My rectangle has area " + theArea);
        System.out.println("Rectangle Perimiter " + thePerimeter);

        Rectangle newRect = new Rectangle(10, 20);

    }
}

public class Rectangle {

    private double width, length;
    private double len, wid;

    public void setWidth(double w) {
        width = w;
    }

    public void setLength(double ln) {
        length = ln;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public double area() {
        double a;
        a = length * width;
        return a;
    }

    public double perim() {
        double pr;
        pr = (length * 2) + (width * 2);
        return pr;
    }

    public Rectangle(double len, double wid) {
    }
}
```

Sorry about the code blocks, indent is a bit weird for me in Safari.

The 'Rectangle' class compiles without error.

but the 'RectangleDemo' class compiler error is this.

```
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g RectangleDemo.java
RectangleDemo.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Rectangle()
location: class Rectangle
        Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle ();
```

I'm compiling on an 07 Macbook running OSX 10.7.5

I haven't added anything to the constructor's code yet because I can't even get the program to find it without error.

All the reading I've been doing has been helpful to me learning more about JAVA but I'm at my wits end with this program.  To make things worse, I bet its just a stupid, little typo on my part.

Comment: You are trying to call a constructor for `Rectangle` which takes no arguments. The only constructor in `Rectangle` requires two arguments. You just need to fix that.

Answer (score 7):

I think the piece of the puzzle you are missing is this little [java gem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html):

- When you *don't* have any constructors defined, there is an implicit no-args constructor.
- When you define a constructor with arguments, the implicit no-args constructor vanishes.

This catches out many programmers new to java (I admit, it caught me out).

The particularly unexpected thing about this is you can have clients using a class (without constructors), and you add an args constructor, and you think "I'm *adding* code, so this *can't* cause any problems", then suddenly their code breaks. That's because you are silently also *removing* code.

One good rule to remember is: If you have a constructorless class being used by others, and you define an args constructor, always add a no-args one too.

Comment: This can definitely be a confusing thing for a new Java programmer. I'm not sure how clearly it is mentioned in most books, but it is briefly mentioned in the Java tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). Unfortunately they don't just plainly state it like @Bohemian did here.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Rectangle (double len, double wid) {

}
```

This is your constructor for a Rectangle object.
This means that when you create a rectangle object, you need to pass it two doubles, the first is the length and the second is the width.
You have this:

```
Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle ();
```

But that is not sending the required params. You are trying to call a constructor for a rectangle which takes no params.
You should change this for example to:

```
Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle (1.5, 2.3);
```

This would make a Rectangle object with length 1.5 and width 2.3

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

The error is completely correct.

The only constructor in the `Rectangle` class takes two arguments; you aren't passing any.